# Right exclusive join in Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, join, merge

I am trying to join df1 and df2, so that df1 is merged with df2 on the keys that are not common between them.
For instance, given df1:

```
    cluster     SMILES_x    SMILES_y
0   381.0       COc1cc2c... COc1ccc2cc3[n+]        
1   548.0       O=C(CCN1... O=C(C=Cc1ccccc1)NCCCCN1CCc2ccccc2C1
```

and given df2:

```
cluster     SMILES
0   381.0   O=C(Nc1cccn2ncnc12)C(F)(F)F
1   721.0   COc1cc(SC)ccc1C(=O)NCCc1c[nH]c2ccccc12
2   840.0   CC(C)CCNC(=O)C1CCN(S(=O)(=O)c2ccc3c(c2)CC(C)N3...
3   381.0   O=C(NCc1ccco1)c1cc([N+](=O)[O-])ccc1N1CCOCC1
```

row 0 from df2 could be matched with row 3 and 4 of df1, but NOT row 0, 1 or 2 since they share the same cluster number.

I have tried the following code, but it only finds the common matches, so it is not helpful:

```
supplement = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'cluster', how = 'outer', indicator = True)
supplement = supplement[supplement['_merge']=='right_only']
```

The head of the output in this case should be:

```
    cluster  SMILES_x   SMILES_y    cluster  SMILES_z
0   381.0    COc1cc...  COc1ccc2... 721.0    COc1cc(SC)ccc1C...     
1   381.0    COc1cc...  COc1ccc2... 840.0    CC(C)CCNC(=O)C1CCN...
2   548.0    O=C(CC...  O=C(C=Cc... 381.0    O=C(Nc1cccn2ncnc12)C...
3   548.0    O=C(CC...  O=C(C=Cc... 721.0    COc1cc(SC)ccc1C... 
...
```

Comment: Please show us what you think the results should look like.

Comment: Try `supplement[supplement['_merge'].isin(['left_only', 'right_only'])`

Comment: I only have 'both' _merge, I believe 'outer' is not really the type of join I am looking for...

Comment: What you want is WenYoBen's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This more like cross join and remove the same id

```
df1.assign(key=1).merge(df2.assign(key=1),on='key').loc[lambda x : x['cluster_x']!=x['cluster_y']]
```

Comment: I think that could work, but my dataset is too big so it throws me this error Unable to allocate array with shape (1858546656,) and data type int64. Do you think there is any other way of taking an arbitrary number of matches by random?

Comment: @Daniel this just a common solution, if you data is too big , you may need to start build your own arg for the join merge .